# How can I find the associated resource's media url within the response when using Python EVE's RETURN_MEDIA_AS_URL

Tags: python, eve

I've enabled RETURN_MEDIA_AS_URL within my settings.py.  I have a schema that looks like this:

```
schema = {
    'type': 'dict',
    'schema': {
        'action': {
            'type': 'string',
            'default': 'Favorite'
        },
        'description': {
            'type': 'string',
            'default': 'I really liked this.'
        },
        'hyperlink': {
            'type': 'string',
            'default': 'http://placehold.it/300x300'
        },
        'pic': {
            'type': 'media'
        }
    }
}
```

After generating a resource, the response items payload looks like this:

```
{
  "_updated": "2015-05-06T17:30:32Z",
  "description": "I really liked this.",
  "hyperlink": "http://placehold.it/300x300",
  "pic": {
        "upload_date": "2015-05-06T17:30:32Z",
        "length": 119861,
        "content_type": "image/png",
        "file": null,
        "name": "shoebot.png"
   },
   "_links": {
       "self": {
            "href": "notification/554a4fb8803bd747eb725d4a",
            "title": "Notification"
       }
   },
   ...
}
```

I have an API Prefix that looks like this:  /api/v1/
I can't seem to figure out what GET url will respond back with my shoebot.png image from Eve.

Thanks for any advice to nudge me in the right direction :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Returning media as URL is currently on the [development branch](http://python-eve.org/changelog.html#in-development), targeted for v0.6 release. So unless you are running from the `development` branch, this feature is not yet available to you. You can of course pull it down and experiment with it freely if so you wish.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Bingo!  I've been using 0.5.4 and completely overlooked which branch this was targeted to.  Thanks Nicola.  Love how the project has evolved.  I've found it extremely flexible and powerful to solve just about any use case I can dream up around REST APIs :-) .  With regard to your answer, assume that setting MEDIA_ENDPOINT is only relevant if I want to customize rather than using the default.

Comment: Ah yes of course. I'm updating the answer to avoid confusion.